# Running bunch of python methods on a single piece of data

Tags: python, methods

I would like to run a set of methods given some data. I was wondering how I can remove or chose to run different methods to be run. I would like to groups them within a larger method so I can call it; and it will go along the lines of test case.

In code: Now these are the methods that process the data. I may sometimes want to run all three or a subset thereof to collect information on this data set.

```
def one(self):
    pass
def two(self):
    pass
def three(self):
    pass
```

I would like to be able to call of these methods with another call so I dont have to type out run this; run this. I am looking for elegant way to run a bunch of methods through one call so I can pick and choose which gets run.

Desired result

```
def run_methods(self, variables):
     #runs all three or subset of
```

I hope I have been clear in my question. I am just looking for an elegant way to do this. Like in Java with reflection.

Please and thanks.

Comment: Java reflection is anything but elegant :)

Comment: If you use it correctly, and only then it is. it often isn't :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send the methods you want to run as a parameter:

```
def runmethods(self, variables, methods):
   for method in methods:
       method(variables)
```

then call something like:

```
self.runmethods(variables, (method1, method2))
```

This is the nice thing of having functions as first-class objects in Python

For the question of the OP in the comment (different parameters for the functions), a dirty solution (sorry for that):

```
def rest(a, b):
    print a - b

def sum(a, b):
    print a + b

def run(adictio):
    for method, (a, b) in adictio.iteritems():
        method(a, b)

mydictio = {rest:(3, 2), sum:(4, 5)}

run(mydictio)
```

You could use other containers to send methods together with their variables but it is nice to see a function as the key of a dictionary

if your methods/functions use different numbers of parameters you can not use

```
for method, (a,b) in adictio.iteritems():
```

because it expects the same number of parameters for all methods. In this case you can use *args:

```
def rest(*args):
    a, b = args
    print a - b

def sum(*args):
    a, b, c, d, e = args
    print a + b + c + d + e

def run(adictio):
    for method, params in adictio.iteritems():
        method(*params)

mydictio = {rest:(3, 2), sum:(4, 5, 6, 7, 8)}

run(mydictio)
```

Comment: @joaquin what if different methods have different variable requirements; can you give a more explicit code example. I like where you are going with this.

Comment: @dusty, if your methods need arbitrary params, then you can pass a tuple of tuples... ((method, *args, **kwargs), (method2, *args, **kwargs)), and execute the method with method[0](method[1],method[2])

Comment: @josh link to better understand what you mean please

Comment: d is the parameter of run. d is a dictionary. It takes the value of a. I modify the code to make it more obvious. It's my fault: one-letter names are not a good idea for good python style

Comment: @joaquin thats what I was looking for! if you could tell me to get all the methods in a class so I dont have to rewrite the call everytime I add new methods

Comment: @dusty, if you're getting all the methods at runtime, then you don't know their signature and you won't know what data needs to be passed to them. You can discover their signature, but then you're left with a whole bunch of methods that you want to optionally execute, and how do you determine that?

Comment: I would pass in a a dictionary that optionally lets thing be true or false if it had already been detected in the data it no longer needs to be running.

Answer (score 2):

If you normally do all the functions but sometimes have exceptions, then it would be useful to have them done by default, but optionally disable them like this:

```
def doWalkDog():
    pass

def doFeedKid():
    pass

def doTakeOutTrash():
    pass

def doChores(walkDog=True, feedKid=True, takeOutTrash=True):
    if walkDog: doWalkDog()
    if feedKid: doFeedKid()
    if takeOutTrash: doTakeOutTrash()

# if the kid is at grandma's...
# we still walk the dog and take out the trash
doChores(feedKid=False)
```

Comment: is there a way to get the methods within a class with having to write it down explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the comment regarding passing arbitrary values:

```
def runmethods(self, methods):
   for method, args in methods.iteritems():
       method(*args[0], **args[1])

runmethods( {methodA: ([arg1, arg2], {'kwarg1:' 'one', 'kwarg2'})},
            {methodB: ([arg1], {'kwarg1:' 'one'})} 
          )
```

But at this point, it's looking like more code than it's worth!